# Cannot debug local C# code used in U-SQL since VS2017 15.7.1 upgrade; Local run failed or was terminated

Tags: c#, debugging, u-sql

*(I also posted this a couple days ago on the MSDN Data Lake forum, so I thought I'd expand the audience here)*

I have a custom extractor, as well as a custom assembly that have been working for the past several weeks+ - I have been able to debug locally stepping into the code up until Friday morning.  I am still able to Submit the U_SQL script locally and it successfully runs producing a local output file, but when I F5 to debug I "**Local run failed or was terminated**" and the output file is not created.

Is there a detailed log somewhere to see what exception is being thrown?  Nothing in the event viewer.

I have completely reinstalled VS2017 back to 15.0, then tried updated to just 15.6.x but get the latest 15.7.1 again.  Same issue with multiple projects now.

Has anyone encountered this?

[error message display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYAMS.png)

Answer (score 1):

The root cause has been identified.  It is because of a bug in Windows 10 1803 update that causes failure when creating a local mailslot for IPC. This IPC is used during local debug session.    The Windows team is working on a fix now.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative fix in the development tools was release yesterday as version 2.3.4000.3 of ADL Tools.   You will need to upgrade it in VisualStudio 2017 -> Tools -> Extension and Updates -> Updates -> Visual Studio Marketplace.
For VS 2015 users, please get the update from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49504

For users who want to know more details, the correspondent Windows OS fix is done but not yet available. The alternative fix in development tools is to use \\.\mailslot instead of \\localhostname\mailslot